# Using Anchored Objects within a text frame

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am creating a text frame that consists of multiple elements that need to dynamically move according to what is filled in and whats not.

The text frame has a title, an image, a subtitle and a description. At any given time one of those may not be there, so I need everything else to move up (or down) so there is no white space between elements.

I will need to create two text frames for different situations, one will have the elements collapsing up to the top of the frame, the other will have the elements collapsing to the bottom.

My text frame now all collapses to the top, because I have not controlled the position of the anchor.

How do I change the position or direction the anchored objects collapse?

Do I have to apply that rule to each element (title,image,subtitle,description) within the text frame, in order for them all to function the same? Or am i assigning the setting to just the text frame itself?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The collapsing of the inner elements of a text frame is independent of the anchored objects, in fact a nested object is *subordinated* to the content of that text frame.

How the interior elements of a text frame collapse are defined from the **Text Frame Options**, <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> Win. It's aligned on top by default.

[image]

But it's possible to change this to bottom align and create a **Text Frame Object Style** with this option.

[image]

From this same window you can make the **Fit Frame to Content** automatically top or bottom:

[image: autosize up]

[image: autosize bottom]